# Does one elemental damage type stack on itself?

Tags: borderlands-2

If I have a fire SMG and trigger the burn damage, can the fire dot be triggered multiple times so it stacks with itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all elemental damage over time stacks. This is one of the reasons that a fast-firing elemental weapon is excellent.