# How many elemental effects can I stack?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there a maximum number of elemental effects I can (practically) stack in Borderlands 2, or can I keep stacking them on as long as my rate of fire, elemental effect chance and Damage over Time duration permits? I know for example more than one stack can affect a target; you can tell as more and more numbers jump off a target indicating DOT as you add more stacks, but there's otherwise no visual indicator.

For some math I've got a nearly 50% chance of inflicting Corrosion (10% chance on gun, 30% additive boost to that percentage from Siren skills, 6.some% chance from Badass rank) on an 8.0 rate of fire SMG. I've got 8 seconds before the first stack runs out. Assuming 50% chance per bullet times 8 for 8 seconds I could get around 32 stacks on one target in 8 seconds for an extremely brief period of time. Is that doable or is there a lower limit for elemental DoT stacks?

I am asking how many stacks can be on a target at once. I am *not* asking how to calculate my chance of causing an elemental effect.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85736/does-one-elemental-damage-type-stack-on-itself

Comment: @Hex doesn't really answer my question though; I know they stack, I want to know if there's a limit to how many I can paint on one target at a time

Comment: fair enough, just related then :)

Comment: Small failure: you don't get +30% chance to trigger an elemental attack with a weapon by siren's talent, but a 30% HIGHER chance. Example: Your weapon indicates a 10% chance to proc fire, with the siren's talent (think it's called Flicker) you will now have 13% (0,1 + 0,3*0,1).

Comment: Yeah, I know that, doesn't really matter though, I'm not asking about doing it with a non-elemental gun.

Comment: i dont know for sure but, I have a blaster with really fast firing speed 10+ and I can see 4 or 5 stacked at a time, I will make sure this by firing on dummy at Marcus. IMHO its unlimited times but max i got for solo is like 4,5 or more its really hard to tell how many. I think a better way to confirm this is to host 4 player game, equip different elemental weapon with high rate of fire and elemental chance. fire away on marcus's target practice. Try to count it :) it could be hard by the way. In conclusion i will say you can have unlimited stacks

Comment: I deleted the dupe answer of dat's comment, but it'd be easier for yourself to simply fix the question (maybe mention one of those burst fire sniper rifles or something.)

Comment: @badp fix how? I thought it was fairly clear I'm asking about how many stacks add up, not how the %s work

Comment: @BenBrocka I was just suggesting to fix that bit as it just distracts people from the issue at hand, that's all

Answer (score 2):

I believe You can have 3 effects on an enemy at one time, but slag does not count towards this limit.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen more than three on one. And I've definitely seen more than one stack of Fire plus multiple Corrode/Shock (Ruin + Helios alone will do this)

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to how many elementals can stack. You can stack how many ever elementals you want.

You can stack all elements ie. Fire, Shock, Corrosion, Slag can all be stacked on a enemy at the same time.